# How to save a new trigger on an existing Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, taskservice

I'm using the TaskService class to create and edit Windows Scheduled Tasks. One problem I have is how to save a new trigger on an existing Scheduled Task. The trigger does not seem to save.

```
var task = new TaskService().FindTask("My Scheduled Task");
BootTrigger trigger = new BootTrigger();
var td = task.Definition;
//td.Triggers.Count = 1 at this point
td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
//td.Triggers.Count = 2 at this point
```

So the code seems okay. But if I open the Scheduled Task in Windows, only 1 trigger is shown and not the one I added.  If I run my code again, the trigger count is back to 1, so it seems like there should be some Commit() or Save() function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing re-registering the task definition.

```
var ts = new TaskService();
var task = ts.FindTask("My Scheduled Task");
BootTrigger trigger = new BootTrigger();
var td = task.Definition;
//td.Triggers.Count = 1 at this point
td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
//td.Triggers.Count = 2 at this point
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("My Scheduled Task", td);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a "Access is denied." exception on the RegisterTaskDefinition command. I can create the task and 1st trigger successfully with code without this error. But at least I have something else to struggle with now.

Comment: try running it as admin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator/2818776#2818776